# how to create a list by forloop in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, uipath, uipath-studio

Excuse me,i want to create an array by vb.net
How can i do it?

I would like to use a for-loop to finish it.

this is an array:

```
 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,.....,100]
```

Comment: What have you tried already?  Also, look up generics like List(of T) and the .ToArray() method.

Comment: How important is it that it gives you a static array? A for loop may have any number or iterations, a dynamic array like a List would be easier to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to use a For loop since you just want sequential numbers. Here is sort of a one-liner solution:

```
Dim collection() As Integer = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToArray()
```

Fiddle: [Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GSBBXo)

Otherwise, if you're limitted to using a For/Next, then create a collection with a set upper-bounds and then loop from 1 to 100:

```
Dim collection(99) As Integer
For c As Integer = 1 To 100
    collection(c - 1) = c
Next
```

Fiddle: [Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/B6ci89)